# Changing and saving a redirect with Passport.js in different circumstances

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

im writing a website using express and passport for authentication (and mongodb as database) and i know how i can authenticate users and how i can restrict certain pages so only logged-in users can access them. but i have one question to which i cant find the answer anywhere:

if a user tries to go to a restricted webpage and it notices a user is not logged in using req.isAuthenticated() it redirects the user to the login page and then when the user logged in it redirect the user to their profile page. normally this is fine but in this case the user tried to go to another restricted page that is not the profile page.

how can i redirect the user to the profile page when he/she tries to log in but when he/she just tries to acces a page that is restricted ask him/her to login and then redirect him/her to the page he/she tried to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own middleware similar to below to handle the redirect on that route:

```
this.ensureAuthenticatedOrSendToLogin = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  return res.redirect('/login');
};
```

You could then add a field to the session to store a redirectTo with the url from the request: `req.session.redirectTo = req.url` and load it after login before the successful redirect after auth.

A simplified version you could use:

```
this.saveRedirect = (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.redirectTo = req.url; // could pass this in from query too if redirect should be different!
  return next();
};

this.checkRedirect = (req, res, next) => {
  const { redirectTo } = req.session;
  if (redirectTo) {
    const redirect = redirectTo;
    req.session.redirectTo = undefined; // reset session field so its not carried out again if you call this without saving again
    return res.redirect(redirect);
  }
  return next();
};
```

Comment: thanks man. looks like a great solution. i kinda found a rly hacky solution (by adding invisible fields to an html form) but that now just seems dumb :P. ill try it out as soon as i get the chance.

Comment: also, DONT do what i did by adding invisible fields to an html form... its a lot of work and it isnt a nice solution....